# Unable to find matched documents using $elemMatch

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a JSON data like:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5e887ee61c7f053dc8702214",
        "leadName": "Experienced",
        "leads": [
            {
                "name": "Joey",
                "mobile": 1524524678,
                "_id": "5e887ee61c7f053dc8702212",
                "leadType": "5e887a470962a53b80e0b57a"
            },
            {
                "name": "Ben",
                "mobile": 1524524678,
                "_id": "5e887ee61c7f053dc8702213",
                "leadType": "5e887a470962a53b80e0b57a"
            }
        ]
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5e887fa91c7f053dc8702217",
        "leadName": "Fresher",
        "leads": [
            {
                "name": "Rachel",
                "mobile": 1524524678,
                "_id": "5e887fa91c7f053dc8702215",
                "leadType": "5e887a470962a53b80e0b578"
            },
            {
                "name": "Chandler",
                "mobile": 1524524678,
                "_id": "5e887fa91c7f053dc8702216",
                "leadType": "5e887a470962a53b80e0b57a"
            }
        ]
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

Each of the objects belonging to the `leads` array has a `leadType` associated with them. The `leadType` is a reference _id from another schema. What I am trying here is to access all the objects/ documents that match the particular `leadType` passed as a request.

Three out of four of my users have a `leadType` associated with a `"leadType": "5e887a470962a53b80e0b57a"`.

When I query to retrieve these 3 users details with `"leadType": "5e887a470962a53b80e0b57a"`, it only matches the single user from the first array of object. and one from second array of object.

I tried foloowing queries:

```
exports.leads_by_type = (req, res) => {
  const { leadtypeid } = req.body;

  Lead.find({"leads.leadType": leadtypeid}, {leads: { $elemMatch : {leadType: leadtypeid}}}, (err, result) => {
    res.json(result)
  });
  //this query returns only the first document of first object's array of objects and one from second.


  //OR EVEN THIS ONE       

  Lead.aggregate([
    {$match: {userId: req.user.userId}},
    {$unwind: "$leads"},
    {$match: {"leads.leadType": leadtypeid}}
  ], (err, test) => {
    res.json({test})
  });
  //this query returns empty array []

};
```

I need to return every document one or more, who just matches the given id. I tried following lots of approaches over SO and this particular question [Make $elemMatch (projection) return all objects that match criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19696282/make-elemmatch-projection-return-all-objects-that-match-criteria) (that seemed like my use-case) but none of them seems to solve my problem.

Please help to resolve this. It's really important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your second solution is returning an empty array as you are searching for documents with `_id = leadtypeid` in the first `$match`, but there is no documents with this id, I mean by document is the whole object which has

```
_id = "5e887ee61c7f053dc8702214" or "5e887fa91c7f053dc8702217"
```

as long as you are interested only in `leadtypeid`, so we can add this to the first $match, but this is not enough as this will search for documents which have this leadtype, so the result will contain the fourth lead you don't want
that's why we use the $unwind, to get each document which has this lead type in a separate document
and then match the needed leadtype, to get rid of the fourth leadtype

so the query will be like that

> note: replace `'5e887a470962a53b80e0b57a'` with `leadtypeid`

```
db.collectionName.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $match: {
                'leads.leadType': '5e887a470962a53b80e0b57a' // this to find all the documents which have this lead type
            }
        },
        {
            $unwind: '$leads' // to have multiple documents, each document with leads array of only one item in it, the lead type we are searching for only
        },
        {
            $match: {
                'leads.leadType': '5e887a470962a53b80e0b57a' // to get the documents that have this lead type and get rid of any other lead type
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

the result of this query will be

```
{
    "_id" : "5e887ee61c7f053dc8702214",
    "leadName" : "Experienced",
    "leads" : {
        "name" : "Joey",
        "mobile" : 1524524678,
        "_id" : "5e887ee61c7f053dc8702212",
        "leadType" : "5e887a470962a53b80e0b57a"
    }
}
{
    "_id" : "5e887ee61c7f053dc8702214",
    "leadName" : "Experienced",
    "leads" : {
        "name" : "Ben",
        "mobile" : 1524524678,
        "_id" : "5e887ee61c7f053dc8702213",
        "leadType" : "5e887a470962a53b80e0b57a"
    }
}
{
    "_id" : "5e887fa91c7f053dc8702217",
    "leadName" : "Fresher",
    "leads" : {
        "name" : "Chandler",
        "mobile" : 1524524678,
        "_id" : "5e887fa91c7f053dc8702216",
        "leadType" : "5e887a470962a53b80e0b57a"
    }
}
```

hope this is what you're looking for

Comment: It worked. Thanks alot :). Just a little fix if anyone around here comes for the same: Convert the `id` needed to search as an `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(idToSearchFor)`

Comment: @Mohammad. Just a little query. Even if I remove the first `$match`, it still gives me the required result. Can you help me explain this query behavior?

Comment: First, yes you need to convert that string to ObjectId, so the aggregate can understand it.
Second, in this case yes it's not mandatory to add any thing to the first match, as we are interested in the leadType only, for example, if you need to get the leads who have 'Experienced' leadName, and this leadType, then you will need the first match, to filter the documents to get only the 'Experienced' documents before unwinding, hope it's more clear now