# how to query returns all values in the array that match the criteria in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I want to return all values in the array that match the criteria.

but when I query, It returns only one result.

This is the value of my DB.

```
[{
    "channel": "a",
    "video": [
        {
            "name": 1
            "status": ''
        },
        {
            "name": 2
            "status": 'err'
        },
        {
            "name": 3
            "status": 'err'
        }
    ]
},
{
    "channel": "b",
    "video": [
        {
            "name": 4
            "status": 'err'
        },
        {
            "name": 5
            "status": 'err'
        },
        {
            "name": 6
            "status": ''
        }
    ]
}]
```

I want a get result like this

```
[
{
    "channel": "a",
    "video": [
        {
            "name": 2
            "status": 'err'
        },
        {
            "name": 3
            "status": 'err'
        }
    ]
},
{
    "channel": "b",
    "video": [
        {
            "name": 4
            "status": 'err'
        },
        {
            "name": 5
            "status": 'err'
        }
    ]
}
]
```

but when I using my code

```
var errData = await DB.find({
            'video.status' : { $in : 'err' }
        }, 
        {
            'channel': true,
            'video' : {
                $elemMatch : {
                    'status': { $in : 'err' }
                }
            }
        } )
```

it returns like this

```
[
{
    "channel": "a",
    "video": [
        {
            "name": 2
            "status": 'err'
        }
    ]
},
{
    "channel": "b",
    "video": [
        {
            "name": 4
            "status": 'err'
        }
    ]
},
]
```

how can I fix it in mongoose(don't use aggregate)?

If it is impossible without using an aggregate, how can I make it by using an aggregate?

would you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) explain:

> The $elemMatch operator limits the contents of an  field from the query results to contain only the **first** element matching the $elemMatch condition

That's why you get only one element for each document.

Also, it seems (look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19696282/13464279)) that is not possible without aggregation.

Using aggregation you can use [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) in this way:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "video": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$video",
          "as": "v",
          "cond": {"$eq": ["$$v.status","err"]}
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RWoOdTmZT_-)